# Как остановить, а затем снова запустить экземпляр базы данных Oracle?

Tags: windows, oracle

Здравствуйте.

Моя цель создать новый экземпляр базы данных Oracle с определённым именем.
 Я назвал его 'orcl'. Но после добавления нового экземпляра в базу данных, необходимо этот новый экземпляр базы данных ещё и перезапустить.

Всё бы ничего, только следующие команды, что я нашёл для достижения подобной операции работают только в Linux/Unix:

```
$srvctl stop database -d orcl
$srvctl start database -d orcl
```

А мой сервер базы данных Oracle установлен на Windows :)

Я знаю заранее, что вы скажете типа, что "зачем на нём вы сервер БД развёртывали ?" и.т.д., поэтому отвечаю сразу: для меня пока очень удобно изучать технологии через Windows, так как в отличии от *nix эта ОС проста в использовании, но уже когда я в реальной задаче буду поднимать сервер, то только на Linux/Unix.

Я попытался эти команды использовать в командной строке Windows, но они также не работают("srvctl" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.).

**Вопрос:** Как ещё можно остановить, а затем снова запустить экземпляр 'orcl'?

Может есть и другой способ перезапустить экземпляр базы данных? Если есть, то умоляю детально его описать.

Если нет, то прошу, скажите: Как установить службу srvctl на Windows, чтобы можно было бы её запустить там же с командной строки и через неё уже перезапустить мой экземпляр базы данных 'orcl'? А то что-то гугл мне выдаёт только инфу об установке экземпляра базы данных для пользователей Linux/Unix.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b32010/admin.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На Windows зайдите как пользователь который в группе ORA_DBA. Если вы установили Oracle, то Вы должны быть в этой группе.
Вызовете интерпретатор команд и там зайдите в sqlplus:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Aug 31 19:31:36 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  820236288 bytes
Fixed Size                  1339628 bytes
Variable Size             662703892 bytes
Database Buffers          150994944 bytes
Redo Buffers                5197824 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL>
SQL> -- теперь остановим
SQL>
SQL> shutdown
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , а то я уже в отчаянии стал создавать отдельную группу в windows(для ASM и БД) , при этом просто забыв как называется группа , к которой должна совершаться аутентификация к БД по умолчанию :-D

Comment: Пожалуйста! А почему не посотрели ссылочку в комментарии? Там вроде всё описано.